# What should $a, b \in\Bbb{R}$ be that polinom $x^5+ax^3+b\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ would have at least one non-zero repeated root.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

What should $a, b\in\Bbb{R}$ be that polinom $x^5+ax^3+b\in\Bbb{R}[x]$ would have at least one non-zero repeated root.

Well, what I found out by myself are there: $$1)\quad  b=0,\quad then\quad
x^5+ax^3=x^3(x^2+a),\quad a\in\Bbb{R}$$
$$2) \quad a=0,\quad then\quad x^5+b=0, \quad x=-b^{\frac{1}{5}}, \quad b=n^5,\quad n\in\Bbb{R}$$
But these are only several variants...

Comment: Pretty weird wording and pretty hard to understand: do you mean to find out the values of the coefficients $\;a,b\in\Bbb  R\;$ ( there is no $\;c\;$ !) such that the quintic has **at least** two repeated roots? Negating too much can be confusing...at least for me.

Comment: @DonAntonio I think "not less than one" would mean at least one.

Comment: @PaulSundheim Perhaps...I honestly don't know. Maybe the poster will address this question.

Comment: Sorry, it's really hard to translate the exercise from Lithuanian to English in mathematical terminology.
Simply telling, I just need to find this polinom would have at least one non-zero repeated root.

Comment: If a polynomial has a repeated root $x_1$ then $f'(x_1)=0$.

Comment: As to why the repeated root $x_1$ must satisfy $f'(x_1)=0$ for a polynomial; since we have for some polynomial $g(x)$ that $f(x)=(x-x_1)^2g(x)$ from that $f'(x)=2(x-x_1)g(x)+(x-x_1)^2g'(x)=(x-x_1)(2g(x)+(x-x_1)g'(x))$

Comment: And, of course, a=b=0 has a rerepeated root.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^5+ax^3+b$. If $\phi$ is a repeated root, then $f(\phi)=f'(\phi)=0$.

$$f'(\phi)=5\phi^4+3a\phi^2$$

$$\phi f'(\phi)-5f(\phi)=0$$

$$5\phi^5+3a\phi^3-5\phi^5-5a\phi^3-5b=0$$

$$-2a\phi^3-5b=0$$

So $f(\phi)=(\phi^2+a)(\frac{-5b}{2a})+b=0$.

$$\phi^2=\frac{-3a}{5} \quad\text{or}\quad b=0$$

$b=0$ is an answer.

If $b\ne0$, then

$$\left(\frac{-3a}{5}\right)^3=\phi^6=\left(\frac{-5b}{2a}\right)^2$$

That is $108a^5+3125b^2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $x^5+ax^3+b$ has (at least) a repeated root iff its [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is zero, i.e. iff $b=0$ or $108 a^5 + 3125 b^2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints**:

If $\;f(x)=x^5+ax^3+b\;$ , then a root is multiple iff it is also a root of the polynomial's derivative:

$$f'(x)=5x^4+3ax^2=x^2(5x^2+3a)$$

so if $\;b=0\;$ then $\;x=0\;$ is a multiple root, otherwise , if $\;w\neq0\;$ is a multiple root, it must be that both

$$\begin{cases}w^5+aw^3+b=0\implies&a=-\cfrac{w^5+b}{w^3}\\{}\\
5w^2+3a=0\implies&a=-\cfrac{5w^2}3\end{cases}\;\;\;\implies 3w^5+3b=5w^5\implies$$$${}$$

$$\implies2w^5=3b\implies w=\sqrt[5]\frac{3b}2$$

Try now to find out the conditions on the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of your polynomial is $b^2 (108 a^5 + 3125 b^2)$.  There is a repeated root iff this is $0$.  That occurs of course for $b=0$, but then the root in question is $0$.  Otherwise, you want $a = (-3125 b^2/108)^{1/5}$.